# NPM not recognising my module (requiring unknown module)

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, react-native

I'm working an a React-Native app, and am writing my components into different files, exporting them and importing them wherever they're needed. This is working fine in all instances instead of one, where npm keeps throwing a '*Requiring unknown module*'-error.

My structure is as follows:

- navigator

  - Navigator.js
  - NavBar.js

In *NavBar.js*, I am exporting my component like so:

```
class NavBar extends Component {  
    ...
}
export default NavBar;
```

And importing it in *Navigator.js* like so:

```
import NavBar from './NavBar';
```

The complete message I get on my device when trying to run the app is as follows:
**Requiring unknown module "./NavBar". If you are sure the module is there, try restarting the packager or running "npm install".**

I have tried both those things (multiple times) to no avail.
I must be looking over something stupid, but can't seem to find it. Can anyone else see what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: I don't include the `.js` in any other instances, but they work fine.  
I tried it out anyway, but it didn't help.  
Thanks for the reply though.

Comment: Ok, so is the capitalisation exactly `NavBar`? Any chance one of the letters are from the other alphabet or there are invisible characters?

Comment: It is, I have even tried just copying the filename. It just baffles me, since I use those same exports so many times in my project, and that one file just won't be recognised.

Comment: Try to create and import the `Nav.js` file. Would it work fine? If it is - add one letter each step and check.

Comment: After refactoring it to `Nav.js` and back to `NavBar.js`, it suddenly works. I guess I should have tried that earlier. Thanks for helping out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did to get it fixed:
I refactored the file to something else, and back to `NavBar.js`.

This was probably just caused by me misspelling something in the first place.
So don't forget to check, double check and double check again.